# How to wait for dependent modules run function to be completed before initialization

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to develop an app where one module will be dependent on second module. In the first module run function Im trying to fill templatecache with some data from server using http but since http calls are async my second module will run before the first is completed and I get undefined in the result. Below code would make situation more clear

```
   var app = angular.module('main', []).run(["$templateCache",'$http','$timeout', function ($templateCache,$http,$timeout) {
              $timeout(function () {
                  $templateCache.put('ajay', 'ajay');
              }, 1000);
          }
          ]);

          var secondapp = angular.module('plunker', ['main']);
          secondapp.controller('test', function ($scope, $templateCache, $timeout) {
              // get me undefined i want to wait until module main is finished running run function 
              alert($templateCache.get('ajay'));
          });
```

Comment: It's like you are wanting to run the second app from the callback in the first. Would it be awful to have both apps on the main page, loading the second with an `ng-if` triggered within your success callback of the first?  I don't know, I haven't tried..

Answer (score 1):

Embrace asynchronicity:

```
 var app = angular.module('main', []).run(["$templateCache",'$http','$timeout', function ($templateCache,$http,$timeout) {
     $templateCache.put('ajay', $http.get("/data/ajay"));
 }
 ]);

 var secondapp = angular.module('plunker', ['main']);
 secondapp.controller('test', function ($scope, $templateCache, $timeout) {
     $templateCache.get('ajay').then(function (data) {
         alert(data);
     });
 });
```

Comment: Embrace asynchronicity, yes, but not where it doesn't exist.  $templateCache.get() does not return a promise, it returns the data.