# Delay the page unload until the model bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a look up service which connects with the API service to bind the dropdown lists.

```
    var Lookup = angular.module('Lookup', [])
                        .run(function ($window, $rootScope, DropDownLookUp) {

                            debugger;

                            $rootScope.MaritalStatusList = DropDownLookUp.maritalStatusList();

                            $rootScope.ProvinceList = DropDownLookUp.provinceList();

                            $rootScope.GenderList = DropDownLookUp.genderList();

                            $rootScope.ProvinceOfEmploymentList = DropDownLookUp.provinceOfEmploymentList();
                        });
```

I am using $Http.Get method to fetch the data.

```
var maritalStatusList = function () {
    var keyName = "dropdown-maritalstatus-list";
    // debugger;
    var data = StoreData.retrieveStaticData(keyName);
    if (data == null) {
        HttpService.Get(config.apiUrl + "HomeAPI/MaritalStatusLookUp", "maritalStatusList", "maritalStatusList").then(function (results) {
            StoreData.saveStaticData(JSON.stringify(results), keyName);
            data = results;
            return data;
        });
    }
    else {
        return data;
    }
};
```

This look up module is being called when my default App module loads.

Service is getting fired correctly. But my page is getting loaded before the above calls completed. Hence no data displayed in the dropdown.

How do I can delay the page load, until I have all the necessary data?

Comment: i am waiting for similar answer but didnt get answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457005/how-to-wait-for-dependent-modules-run-function-to-be-completed-before-initilizat

Comment: Depending on how your async calls are structured, maybe instead of using a `return` you'd want to use a callback

Comment: It shouldn't matter that the page loads before the data is there, since you have bindings to the data in the controller's model it should update as soon as it's available. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=10m0s straight from the horse's mouth.  Perhaps your problem is that you're not updating the controller based on a service... you can return a promise from the service... Clark Pan another SO user has a good post on it recently I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: The Q/A part of this isn't the same but the code contains a service that returns the promise so you can within the controller set it up to handle the result after the service call returns. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560287/preserving-scope-accross-routed-views/17560774?noredirect=1#comment25547699_17560774

Comment: Look into [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout). Timeout your system until the data arrives.. or lazy load it.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy method** - Use [$routeProvider resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972028/2013981) method. - Delays navigation to a page until all *promises* are fulfilled

---

**Other method - Don't render dom elements or secondary apps:**

.
The gist of the answer below is to simply wrap any necessary dom elements in an `ng-if`, and set the evaluated expression to `true` within the success callback of your `$http` request.  The example below is a bit overkill, in that it's using 2 apps on the page.

---

This is probably an ugly no-no solution, but it does work.  In essence, I'm creating multiple apps on the page (which requires manual bootstrapping).  The second app has a dependency on the first, and is rendered within the fake "success callback" of the first app's fake `$http` via `ng-if`.

Notice there is no `ng-app` reference, because the app is manually bootstrapped using the element's id:

```
<section ng-if="loaded" id="myapp" ng-controller="MyNameIsController">
    My Name is {{FirstName}} {{LastName}}! {{loaded}}
</section>
```

I'm simulating an `$http` request with a `$timeout` in the first app:

```
 HelloWorldApp.run(function($rootScope, $timeout){
     $timeout(function(){
         $rootScope.loaded = true;
     },1500)
 })
```

[Here's the plunker I forked](http://plnkr.co/edit/9AmxVUYxcRyFqoLL3Nlj?p=preview) to get it going.